# How to batch delete files by name

Tags: file

I have hundreds of images some of which are dupes. Their names are file.jpg and file-2.jpg
How can I delete only the dupes with the -2 in the name and keep the others?

Comment: What OS are you working in and are you doing this at a command prompt or terminal?

Comment: Just do `del *-2.jpg` if you are in windows

Comment: Hmmm this was the first thing I did and it had no effect. Win 7 64bit

Comment: @Boris Did you `cd` (change directory) to the directory with the files you want to remove first?

Answer (score 1):

Linux:

```
find . -type f -name '*-2.jpg' -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk (*) works as a multi-character wildcard on nearly all operating systems. This allows you to perform almost any function (like deleting/copying/moving) on a series of files with * and then whatever common text, such as "-2.jpg".

First `cd` (change directory) to the directory your files are in. Then:

In **Windows**:

```
del *-2.jpg
```

In **Linux/Mac**:

```
rm -f *-2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

### Unix

```
rm *-2.jpg
```

### Windows

```
del *-2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using Windows use the following in cmd - 
del *-2.jpg

If your using Mac or Linux use the following in terminal -
rm *-2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

linux: `rm -f *-2.jpg` (This is after changing to that directory in the terminal) 

The '*' is a multi character wild card to grab all file names with any character with '-2.jpg' at the end. `rm` will remove it and `-f` will force the deletion. Be careful as it will not ask again if it is okay to delete the file, but otherwise you would have to type yes for every file... which would be a pain with a lot to remove.